# Applescript to set Track Comment to Rating

Tags: itunes, applescript

I'm trying to develop an applescript that sets the comment tag to the track's rating.  i.e., if it's a 3 star track, I want the comment to say "3 Star".

```
tell application "iTunes"
  set theTrack to (item 1 of (get selection))
  set comment of theTrack to theRating
end tell
```

This isn't working for me.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is that the rating value is just stored as "rating". But iTunes stores the star rating as a value between 0 and 100, so you need to convert from that value to the number of stars.

There might be a smarter way to do this but this code seems to work.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set theTrack to (item 1 of (get selection))
    set theRating to rating of theTrack
    if theRating = 100 then
        set comment of theTrack to "5 Star"
    else if theRating ≥ 80 then
        set comment of theTrack to "4 Star"
    else if theRating ≥ 60 then
        set comment of theTrack to "3 Star"
    else if theRating ≥ 40 then
        set comment of theTrack to "2 Star"
    else if theRating ≥ 20 then
        set comment of theTrack to "1 Star"
    else if theRating = 0 then
        set comment of theTrack to "0 Star"
    end if
end tell
```